# check items of simple_list_item_checked before user interaction

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Using the following to populate my ListView with checkbox-supported list:

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
       new String[] {"item 1", "item 2"}));
```

All what I want is to be able to check some items "programatically" before any interaction from the user!! How can I do this?!

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. When you say "before any interaction from the user", do you mean before the user VIEWS the list or before the user attempts to select an item or scroll the list?

Comment: The best way would be to make your own custom ArrayAdapter and override the getView(). And in your onItemClickListener, you get the object of the item you clicked and "check some items". this link "http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/" might help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [setItemChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) method on the ListView. After configuring the choice mode you can use it to set the check state of the desired rows.